# Print from Browser: PHP and PyWin32 on IIS Server

Tags: php, python, iis, printing

I have a Python file, 'print.py', which exists on an IIS server and can print documents successfully from a network printer using PyWin32.

I have a PHP file, 'print.php', which exists in the same folder on the IIS server and can successfully execute 'print.py' when ran from the command line.

However, when I access 'print.php' from a browser on a separate computer, which has access to the server, nothing happens.

If I modify 'print.py' to simply output text, this works and the text appears in the browser. Only the printing is not happening.

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What happens when you access `print.php` in a browser on the server itself? Specifically, what does `print.php` contain? Please read [ask]. The more relevant detail you can provide the better.

Comment: print.php looks like this: <?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$output = shell_exec("C:\Python27\python.exe print.py");
echo $output;

?> And accessing print.php in a browser on the server does not seem to work!

Comment: What does `shell_exec()` return when you run the script from the web browser? There's a good chance whatever system account IIS is running under simply doesn't have permission to print.